# WCF connection string with DB

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf, connection, wcf-data-services

I have a database of several tables, which is implemented by the WCF service.

Here I create a database and work in the first table.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

using WcfRestFullService.Model;

namespace WcfRestFullService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "CustomerSevice" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select CustomerSevice.svc or CustomerSevice.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class CustomerSevice : ICustomerSevice
    {
        MySQLEntities dc;
        public CustomerSevice()
        {
            dc = new MySQLEntities();
        }

        public List<customer> GetAllCustomer()
        {
            var query = (from a in dc.customers
                         select a).Distinct().Include(c => c.customerpreference);

            List<customer> CustomersList = new List<customer>();

            query.ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                CustomersList.Add(new customer
                {
                    Id_Cus = x.Id_Cus,
                    FirstName_Cus = x.FirstName_Cus,
                    LastName_Cus = x.LastName_Cus,
                    PhoneNum_Cus = x.PhoneNum_Cus,
                    Email_Cus = x.Email_Cus,
                });
            });
            return CustomersList;
        }

        public customer CustomerDetails(string Id_Cus)
        {
            customer Cust = new customer();
            try
            {
                var query = (from a in dc.customers
                             where a.Id_Cus.Equals(Id_Cus)
                             select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
                Cust.Id_Cus = query.Id_Cus;
                Cust.FirstName_Cus = query.FirstName_Cus;
                Cust.LastName_Cus = query.LastName_Cus;
                Cust.PhoneNum_Cus = query.PhoneNum_Cus;
                Cust.Email_Cus = query.Email_Cus;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>(ex.Message);
            }
            return Cust;
        }

        // DELETE

        public void DeleteCustomer(string Id_Cus)
        {
            //MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities(); //check the file Model.edmx->ModelContext.tt->MySQLEntitys

            int k = Convert.ToInt32(Id_Cus);
            customer cur = (from n in dc.customers
                            where n.Id_Cus == k
                            select n).Include(c => c.customerpreference).Include(c => c.orders).Include(c => c.dishesrankings).ToList().First();


            dc.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            dc.customers.Remove(cur);
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Insert/POST

        public void InsertCustomer(customer customerDataContract)
        {
            //MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities();
            customer cust = new customer();
            {
                //cust.Id_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
                cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
                cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
                cust.PhoneNum_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
                cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;
                //}
                Dictionary<string, int> dict = dc.customers.GroupBy(x => x.Email_Cus, y => y.Id_Cus)
                                                                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

                dc.customers.Add(cust);

            //string p = "Vasa";
            customerpreference Cus_Pref = new customerpreference()
            {
                Id_Cus = customerDataContract.Id_Cus,
                Id_Res = 1, // some value
                Name_Dis = "lion", // some value
                Id_Type = 1 // some value
            };
                dc.customerpreferences.Add(Cus_Pref);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                int k = Convert.ToInt32(cust.Id_Cus);
                customer custFromDb = (from n in dc.customers
                                       where n.Id_Cus == k
                                       select n).Include(c => c.customerpreference).Include(c=>c.orders).Include(c=>c.dishesrankings).First();
            }

        }

        //Update/PUT
        public void UpdateCustomer(customer customerDataContract)
        {
            //using (CustomerDataContract Cust = new CustomerDataContract())
            //using (MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities()) 

                int k = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
                customer cust = dc.customers.Where(n => n.Id_Cus == k).FirstOrDefault();

                cust.Id_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
                cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
                cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
                cust.PhoneNum_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
                cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;

                dc.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
}
```

Note the line:

```
 MySQLEntities dc;
        public CustomerSevice()
        {
            dc = new MySQLEntities();
        }
```

After that I start working with another table:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

using WcfRestFullService.Model;

namespace WcfRestFullService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "CustomerPreferences" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select CustomerPreferences.svc or CustomerPreferences.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class CustomerPreferences : ICustomerPreferences, IDisposable
    {


         MySQLEntities dc;                     //LIKE This
        string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;port=3306;database=chik-chak;password=l10ksfnq5h2c";
         public CustomerPreferences() 
         {
            // dc = new MySQLEntities(); //Perhaps the problem is that I'm trying to create a new database, so the data is not imported from the first table, do I need these lines of code ??
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();
         }

        public customerpreference CustomerDetails(string Id_Cus)
        {

                customerpreference Cust = new customerpreference();
            try
            {
                var query = (from a in dc.customerpreferences
                             where a.Id_Cus.Equals(Id_Cus)
                             select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
                Cust.Id_Cus = query.Id_Cus;
                Cust.Id_Res = query.Id_Res;
                Cust.Name_Dis = query.Name_Dis;
                Cust.Id_Type = query.Id_Type;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>(ex.Message);
            }
            return Cust;
        }

        public void DeleteCustomerPreference(string Id_Cus)
        {
            int k = Convert.ToInt32(Id_Cus);
            customerpreference cur = (from n in dc.customerpreferences
                            where n.Id_Cus == k
                            select n).ToList().First();

            dc.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            dc.customerpreferences.Remove(cur);
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }

        public List<customerpreference> GetAllCustomerPreferences()
        {
            //MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
            //conn.Open();
            //MySqlCommand dc = new MySqlCommand();
            //dc.Connection = conn;
            // MySQLEntities dc;
            var query = (from a in dc.customerpreferences 
                         select a).Distinct();

            List<customerpreference> CustomersList = new List<customerpreference>();

            query.ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                CustomersList.Add(new customerpreference
                {
                    Id_Cus = x.Id_Cus,
                    Id_Res = x.Id_Res,
                    Name_Dis = x.Name_Dis,
                    Id_Type = x.Id_Type,
                });
            });
            //dc.Connection = conn;
            //dc.CommandText = query.ToString();
            //conn.Close();
            return CustomersList;
        }

         public void InsertCustomerPreference(customerpreference customerDataContractpreference)
        {
            customerpreference cust = new customerpreference();
            string query = "INSERT INTO tb_customerpreferences VALUES (@Id_Cus, @Id_Res, @Name_Dis,@Id_Type);";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connStr);
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter()
            {
                cust.Id_Cus = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Cus;
            cust.Id_Res = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Res;
            cust.Name_Dis = customerDataContractpreference.Name_Dis;
            cust.Id_Type = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Type; }
            );

            dc.customerpreferences.Add(cust);
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void UpdateCustomerPreference(customerpreference customerDataContractpreference)
        {
            int k = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Cus;
            customerpreference cust = dc.customerpreferences.Where(n => n.Id_Cus == k).FirstOrDefault();

            cust.Id_Cus = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Cus;
            cust.Id_Res = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Res;
            cust.Name_Dis = customerDataContractpreference.Name_Dis;
            cust.Id_Type = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Type;

            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

note the line:

```
 MySQLEntities dc;                     //LIKE This
        string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;port=3306;database=chik-chak;password=l10ksfnq5h2c";
         public CustomerPreferences() 
         {
            // dc = new MySQLEntities(); //Perhaps the problem is that I'm trying to create a new database, so the data is not imported from the first table, do I need these lines of code ??
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();
         }
```

I tried to implement a database connection only in the Insert method

```
 public void InsertCustomerPreference(customerpreference customerDataContractpreference)
        {
            customerpreference cust = new customerpreference();
            string query = "INSERT INTO tb_customerpreferences VALUES (@Id_Cus, @Id_Res, @Name_Dis,@Id_Type);";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connStr);
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter()
            {
                cust.Id_Cus = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Cus;
            cust.Id_Res = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Res;
            cust.Name_Dis = customerDataContractpreference.Name_Dis;
            cust.Id_Type = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Type; }
            );

            dc.customerpreferences.Add(cust);
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
```

and there is an error in this line and in the next line where I add data to the database

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
//or I tried
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connStr);


//Here problem too
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter()
            {
                cust.Id_Cus = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Cus;
            cust.Id_Res = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Res;
            cust.Name_Dis = customerDataContractpreference.Name_Dis;
            cust.Id_Type = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Type; }
            );
```

could you say what am i doing wrong?

Comment: And what is the error please?

Comment: In the first case "The name 'conn' doesnt exist in the current context"
in the second case "Cannot convert from 'string' to 'MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' "

Comment: Because conn is scoped only in your constructor. Copy the new MySqlConnection() and Open() into where you are using the MySqlCommand. Do you have to use ado to insert? What is preventing you from using EF there?

Comment: I also used EF. But the problem is that when I fill in the data in one of the tables, they are not imported into another table. Therefore, I thought it was necessary to register an additional connection string
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305656/wcf-service-with-entity-frameworkrelationship-between-table

Comment: Ok, just try my suggestion.

Comment: This is also my question, but there I described it most extensively. Or if I use EF I do not need to prescribe an additional connection string?

Comment: Let me see your other question

Comment: Thanks, that helped.
but maybe you could tell me the correctness of my next record, because I'm not at all sure about it
//
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter()
            {
                cust.Id_Cus = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Cus;
            cust.Id_Res = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Res;
            cust.Name_Dis = customerDataContractpreference.Name_Dis;
            cust.Id_Type = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Type; }
            );

Comment: When I try this, I get errors:"Invalid initalizer member declarator"(In the cust.Id_Cus = customerDataContractpreference.Id_Cus; )